# Add class to specific days in Bootstrap Datetime picker after data receives from Ajax

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to add active class for available dates in Bootstrap after client receives data from ajax. Calendar on page is not a picker. It always displays after popup.

[image: Calendar]

I tried to set datetime array and added class in "ShowBeforeDay" event. But it doesn't work.

```
var active_dates = ["21/8/2017", "25/8/2017"];
            console.log('main page');
            $('#div_datetime').datepicker(
                {
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                        console.log("da..tata..ta");
                        var d = date;
                        var curr_date = d.getDate();
                        var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
                        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                        var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year

                        if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1) {
                            return {
                                classes: 'activeClass'
                            };
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
            );
```

How  can I add class for specific days in Bootstrap Datetime after data receives from Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) you have to return an **array**, where

`[0]` is either `false` (disabled date) or `true` (enabled date) 
 `[1]` the class to add to this date.

So to fix your code simple replace the last part of it:

```
if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1) return [1, "activeClass"]
else return [0]
```

Comment: "beforeShowDay" event is not triggered when popup shows.

Comment: how do you mean that? the `beforeShowDay` function was called when I tested the code.

Comment: As I said, calendar is not a picker. It will always displays after modal popup. I think it's because "beforeShowDay" doesn't work.

Comment: `beforeShowDay` definitely works. But you have to "refresh" the calendar after you change the dates in the array.You can do this with `$("#div_datetime").datepicker("refresh")`.

Comment: got it. I also need to write code for datepicker outside of $(function ()); scope.